# Excel data not visible in analytics obiee

Tags: odbc, dsn, obiee

I have created a system DSN with oracle BI server driver adding a excel as source data. I was able to create a RPD. Once I logged in to analytic I was able to see the RPD in analysis. But if I select any column and check for the result I get an error like mentioned below. Please help me sort out this issue.

```
Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. [nQSError: 16001] ODBC error state: IM002 code: 0 message: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT 0 s_0, "New"."Sample"."Customer Name" s_1 FROM "New" FETCH FIRST 65001 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Can you check the connection pool in the RPD to see if the connection is working there?

Comment: yes it is working. I am able to view data there.